how to change font size locally in xfce-terminal?
Does anyone know if there's a way to change the font-size in xfce-terminal locally (for just one window), preferably on the command line? It's possible to change it globally (for all terminal windows) through the preferences menu, but I can't find a way to restrict the change to just one window. There are a ton of notes on how to change font colors (link below for example), but I can't find any material regarding font size.
https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

It may be possible, but after trying to figure out how to do something along those lines years ago, I finally gave up and went with gnome-terminal instead. That's because it allows provision of multiple profiles, where a profile can be selected on the command line by, for example, gnome-terminal --profile='profile_name'.

Yeah, that's exactly what I was hoping for with xfce-terminal. Something to keep in mind!

One of the xfce folks helped me out, here's the solution
xfce4-terminal --font "Sans 24"

